# Arduino: Printing values calculated in a library onto the serial monitor

Tags: c++, arduino

I am attempting to get the values from my cooking hacks SPO2 sensor to appear on the Arduino serial monitor, I am using IDE 1.0.6 and the eHealth library V2.4 (July 2015). The sensor is fully operational and values correctly appear on the sensors LED screen but I am struggling to get the values onto the monitor. Any help appreciated, original code can be found on the cooking hacks website as well as the libraries downloaded, eHealth and PinChangeIt (link below).

[Cooking hacks eHealth shield](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/ehealth-biometric-sensor-platform-arduino-raspberry-pi-medical/)

Thanks in advance

```
#include <eHealth.h>
#include <eHealthDisplay.h>


int cont = 0;
void readPulsioximeter();
void MonitorPrint();



void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Serial.println(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation); 

eHealth.initPulsioximeter();
//Attach the inttruptions for using the pulsioximeter.
attachInterrupt(6, readPulsioximeter, RISING);
}

void loop() {



printf("PRbpm : %d",eHealth.getBPM());`
printf("    %%SPo2 : %d\n", eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());
  printf("=============================");

 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);



 delay(500);



void readPulsioximeter(){



cont ++;



if (cont == 500) { //Get only of one 50 measures to reduce the latency
eHealth.readPulsioximeter();
cont = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serial print like this -

```
  Serial.print("PRbpm : %d \t");
  Serial.print(eHealth.getBPM());
  Serial.print(" %%SPo2 : %d\n \t");
  Serial.print(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());
  Serial.print("=============================");
```

Comment: Hello, would you recommend creating a new function or placing this code within one of the functions already in my sketch.

Comment: I have added the code and I am now getting information to print onto the serial monitor so thank you, however the data is not. Should I create variables for the data e.g: "float eHealth.getBPM" and then Serial.print this instead of eHealth.getBPM()

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. Create the variable and update and print it every time in loop. Upvote my answer if it helped you.!